# Unrecognized Windows Sockets error when calling rest API with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, sockets, rest

I use apache httpclient to call a rest API, the code is like this:

```
try {
        String url = "http://"; //rest api url
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() > 299) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        String xmlOutput = "";

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            xmlOutput += output;
        }

        return xmlOutput;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it works fine at my machine and other machines except for one machine that returns this error:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target    host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create 27, 2014 1:28:17 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Connect
INFO: Retrying connect 27, 2014 1:28:17 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Connect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create 27, 2014 1:28:17 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Connect
INFO: Retrying connect 27, 2014 1:28:17 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Connect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create 27, 2014 1:28:17 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Connect
INFO: Retrying connect

java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at test.TestClass.getStringReaderFromGet(TestClass.java:31)
    at test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:17)
```

The machine is running widows 7 Home Basic, service pack 1, 64 bit
CPU: Intel core i5 - 2.5GHz
RAM: 8.0 GB

What's the problem with that machine?

note: all other machines have same specifications and works fine

Comment: According to MSDN it's a "WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT - Service provider failed to initialize.". HTTP failed to initialize?? Did you check the machine's settings for proxies or other shenannigans that mess with plain sockets?

Comment: yes, no proxy is configured!!